# Java. не создает папки для *.class

Tags: java

Собственно читаю этот гайд. 
[IBM java classpath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-classpath-windows/).

Делал все как там описано.

Но, при выполнении команды

```
 javac -d bin src\ru\smirnov\greeting\HelloWorld.java
```

в директории `bin` не создается данная иерархия, а HelloWorld просто лежит в папке `bin`.

Как исправить?

Comment: Думаю, нужно добавить `package ru.smirnov.greeting;` в начало файла `HelloWorld.java`.

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо, @Regent.

Comment: На здоровье. В таком случае я размещу это как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC) ключ `-d` лишь указывает директорию для размещения скомпилированных `.class`-файлов. Для создания необходимой иерархии папок в `bin` в исходном файле `.java` должен быть указан `package`:

```
package ru.smirnov.greeting;
```